# mingw32-make не может собрать тестовый проект cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, ld

На стадии проверки c++ компилятора, cmake выдает ошибку

> is not able to compile a simple test program.

Как я понял ошибка появляется на стадии линковки. Вот ошибки:

> ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++
> ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
> ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s

Я только начал разбираться с cmake, так что не серчайте если вопрос глупый

Comment: Вопрос не глупый, однако в нем отсутствуют шаги, которые позволили бы читающим воспроизвести эту проблему и дать им возможность разобраться с ней, поэтому он бесполезен.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Недостаточно информации для ответа.

Если вы работаете под windows, могу порекомендовать следующее:
установите msys2, откройте терминал, установите `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`.

Команды msys2:

```
pacman -sS gcc # поиск
pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc # установка
```

Затем зайдите в каталог установки msys2  и запустите  mingw64.exe (у меня это `C:\msys64\mingw64.exe`). В открывшемся терминале доступен g++ и /usr/bin/c++, любой CMake его видит (можно ставить через в msys2, можно использовать обычный инсталлятор). В качестве cmake-генератора можно использовать MinGW Makefiles (нужно установить mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-make) или Ninja (можно установить в msys2 или отдельно)

При желании можно добавить терминал в контекстное меню проводника через реестр, решение гуглится, если нужно. Команда для запуска терминала в текущем каталоге: `C:\msys64\mingw64.exe bash`